# Python quits in PhotoImage

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library

The following code makes Python "quit unexpectedly" when trying to create the PhotoImage instance (it prints 1 and quits). I'm on OS X 10.9.5, using Python 2.7.10, ActiveTcl 8.6.4 from ActiveState, running the script from IDLE using Run / Run Module. Any clue? I'm totally new to Python and all the GUI modules

```
import numpy as np
import collections
import math
import Tkinter 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# A root window for displaying objects
root = Tkinter.Tk()  

# Convert the Image object into a TkPhoto object
im = Image.open('samples.png')
print 1
imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im) 
print 2
# Put it in the display window
Tkinter.Label(root, image=imgtk).pack() 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the error message you are seeing

Comment: No message from Python; OS X says "Python quit unexpectedly".

Answer (score 0):

ImageTk.PhotoImage seems to be broken, at least on some systems including Python 2.7 on OS X Sierra.  You can use Tkinter.PhotoImage instead, but it only takes a raw file as an argument which is pitiful.

Answer (score -1):

did you try something link this:

```
import Tkinter 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tkinter.Tk()  
imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='test.jpg') 
Tkinter.Label(root, image=imgtk).pack() 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I just tested your code with imgtk line changed to reflect the answer above. It worked on my computer with python 2.7. It appears the line with image.open is not needed.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. What PIL are you running? How did you install it?