# PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage seg faults

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I've been trying to get a Python library called [EditObj2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/EditObj2) working and have managed to trace the problem to a call to `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage`. Here's the issue, distilled to a code snippet:

```
import Tkinter, PIL, PIL.ImageTk, os

root = Tkinter.Tk()
filename = os.path.expanduser('~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/editobj2/icons/python.png')
pil_image = PIL.Image.open(filename)
image = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=pil_image) # Segmentation fault: 11
image = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=filename) # Segmentation fault: 11
```

I get this problem not only with PNGs, but also with GIFs and JPEGs. The `PIL.Image.open` call seems to be working fine. For example, I can call `pil_image.thumbnail` and get correct output.

I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.5. My Python version info is `Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:04:42)`. Running `pip install --upgrade PIL` tells me I have the latest version, and I have no idea which of the 9,000 Tk packages I should be checking the version of.

It seems possible I have the same problem that was reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910080/python-quits-in-photoimage). Thanks.